# GitLab Docker-in-Docker: how does Docker client in job container discover Docker daemon in `dind` service container?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-in-docker

I have a GitLab CI/CD pipeline that is being run on GKE.

One of the jobs in the pipeline uses a Docker-in-Docker service container so that Docker commands can be run inside the job container:

```yaml
my_job:
  image: docker:20.10.7
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker login -u $USER -p $PASSWORD $REGISTRY
    - docker pull ${REGISTRY}:$TAG
    # ...more Docker commands
```

It all works fine, but I would like to know why. How does the Docker client in the `my_job` container know that it needs to communicate with the Docker daemon running inside the Docker-in-Docker service container, and how does it know the host and port of this daemon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 'discovery' process, really. The docker client must be told about the daemon host through configuration (e.g., `DOCKER_HOST`). Otherwise, the client will assume a default configuration:

0. if the `DOCKER_HOST` configuration is present, this is used. Otherwise:
1. if the default socket (e.g., `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`) is present, the default socket is used.
2. if the default socket is NOT present AND a TLS configuration **is NOT** detected, `tcp://docker:2375` is used
3. If the socket is NOT present AND a TLS configuration **is** present, `tcp://docker:2376` is used

You can see this logic explicitly in the [`docker` dockerfile entrypoint](https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/3bc216c99bcf44b2cf8f8873a705e95e484b0901/20.10/cli/docker-entrypoint.sh#L22-L44).

The docker client can be configured a couple ways, but the most common way in GitLab CI and with the official `docker` image is through the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable. If you don't see this variable in your YAML, it may be set as a project or group setting or may be set on the runner configuration, or is relying on default behavior described above.

It's also possible, depending on your [runner configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersdocker-section) (`config.toml`), that your job is not using the `docker:dind` service daemon at all. For example, if your runner has a `volumes` specification mounting the docker socket (`/var/run/docker.sock`) into the job container and there is no `DOCKER_HOST` (or equivalent) configuration, then your job is probably not even using the service because it would use the mounted socket (per the configuration logic above). You can run `docker info` in your job to be sure of this one way or the other.

Additional references:

- [official `docker` image entrypoint logic](https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/3bc216c99bcf44b2cf8f8873a705e95e484b0901/20.10/cli/docker-entrypoint.sh#L22-L44)
- [Securing the daemon socket](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/protect-access/)
- [GitLab docker in docker docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html)
- [Docker "context"](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/)